# What am I doing wrong with this method definition and call?

Tags: objective-c-blocks

I have this in my class header:

```
typedef void(^DBSuccessBlock)();
typedef void(^DBErrorBlock)(int errorNumber, NSString* description);

- (void) connect:(NSString*) path isFile:(BOOL) flag
        success:(DBSuccessBlock) success
          error:(DBErrorBlock) error;
```

This is how I'm trying to call the method:

```
[db connect:filePathName isFile:YES success:^{
    // initialize db here if necessary
} error:^(int errorNumber, NSString *description) { //error on this line
    NSLog(description);
    return nil;
}];
```

The error line is giving me this compile error: Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void *(^)(int, NSString *_*strong)' to parameter of type 'DBErrorBlock' (aka 'void (^)(int, NSString **_strong)')

The only difference I see is void*  vs  void and I'm not sure why. Can anyone help me figure out why I'm getting this error? Thanks.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that's what your `typedef`s and method declaration look like?

Comment: I copied it directly from my files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the value `nil` in a block with return type `void`. Remove the `return nil` line.

Comment: That was it. Thanks. Still learning the nuances of using blocks. :)